# C# xattr file attributes

Tags: c#, unix, xattr

I'm creating a cross-platform software and I want to know if there is any (easy) way to read/write Unix (Mac OSX/Linux) extended file attributes in C#.
I've just read about `xattr` namespaces, but I haven't found any information about C# implementation or bindings of this feature.

P.S. The only thing I found so far is python-xattr library, but I don't want to use it because:

- I don't want to obligate the users to install Python (there is already Mono/.NET dependency to deal with)
- By using Python I will have a performance decrease (C# is compiled, while Python is interpreted)
- I don't want to rely/depend on external tools (if it's possible), because it's not safe

Comment: Quite often, relying on external libraries is much safer than writing your own in the sense that it will most likely have less bugs. Or did you mean something else by “safe”?

Comment: @svick I think what he meant by safe is managed. C# is a managed language and python is not.

Comment: @thekip is right, I just want to have a fully managed code and possibly homogeneous develop environment. I'm already using C# as glue :D for HTTP5+jQuery+JSON app (running in the xulrunner), native C# code, SQLite/MySQL wrappers-entity providers etc
By adding some other (unmanaged) languages and tools certainly I won't make my app more stable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the syscalls in `Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.*attr*`. 
The nuget assembly is called [Mono.Posix.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard)

Note that the name of the name-value pair is prefixed with a namespace. 
  According to [man 7 xattr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html)

> Currently, the security, system, trusted, and user extended attribute
> classes are defined as described below.  Additional classes may be
> added in the future.

```
public static void Test()
{
    string path = "/root/Desktop/CppSharp.txt";

    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.getxattr()
    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.fgetxattr()
    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.lgetxattr()

    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.setxattr()
    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.fsetxattr()
    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.lsetxattr

    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.llistxattr()
    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.flistxattr()
    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.llistxattr()

    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.removexattr()
    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.fremovexattr()
    // Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.lremovexattr()

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        System.Console.WriteLine("path exists");
    else
        System.Console.WriteLine("path doesn't exists");

    System.Text.Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);
    string[] values = null;

    int setXattrSucceeded = Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.setxattr(path, "user.foobar",
        enc.GetBytes("Hello World äöüÄÖÜ"), Mono.Unix.Native.XattrFlags.XATTR_CREATE);

    if (setXattrSucceeded == -1)
    {
        Mono.Unix.Native.Errno er = Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib.GetLastError();
        string message = Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib.strerror(er);
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662765/how-can-i-get-error-message-for-errno-value-c-language
        System.Console.WriteLine(message);
    } // End if (setXattrSucceeded == -1)

    byte[] data = null;
    long szLen = Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.getxattr(path, "user.foobar", out data);

    string value = enc.GetString(data);
    System.Console.WriteLine(value);

    Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.listxattr(path, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, out values);
    System.Console.WriteLine(values);

    // https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getxattr.2.html
} // End Sub TestExtendedAttributes
```

Answer (score 0):

The final solution might be the following, tell me what do you think?

**FileAttrsManager** is an abstract class, used to create 2 derived classes:

- **FileAttrsManagerDos**: manages advanced attributes using DSOFile.dll*
- **FileAttrsManagerUnix**: manages advanced attributes using IronPython* and python-xattr**

[ * ] http:\\www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8422
[ ** ]  http:\\ironpython.codeplex.com
[ ** * ]  http:\\pypi.python.org/pypi/xatt

Extended attributes operation (such as `SetPropery(string key, object value)` and `GetProperty(string key)` etc) will be managed in a static class (**FileAttrsProvider**) that initializes a **FileAttrsManager** object to one of two derived types i.e.:

```
public static class FileAttrProvider
{

    private static FileAttrReader _reader = null;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
        {
            case PlatformID.MacOSX:
            case PlatformID.Unix:
                _reader = new FileAttrReaderUnix();
                break;
            case PlatformID.Win32NT:
                _reader = new FileAttrReaderDos();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

While the derived type depends on the environment, the original type is used in order to ensure an automatic dispatch of all the methods call on _reader object).

Comment: Don't do this with a static class, use ABSTRACT classes for this !

Comment: @StefanSteiger look at the date, it's 2011! Now we'd use DI to inject a correct version of implementation etc.
Anyway read the answer carefully please, it USES abstract classes, static class is just a facade. Again, today, after 9 years, I'd do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.setxattr would be a better solution, which is in Mono.Posix module.